# Custom React Renderer how to use batch update

Tags: reactjs

I write a custom react renderer using react-reconciler. And the event is different with ReactDom. I want use the batch update ability so that the result is count + 1 rather than count + 2. Is there some solution?

```
const handleClick = () => {
  this.setState(count: this.state.count + 1)
  this.setState(count: this.state.count + 1)
}
```

Comment: React is open source, I'm sure you could look at the ReactDOM source to see how React results in "count + 1". Please update your question to include a relevant code example of the code you've an issue with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example